# Configure virtual host for different websites with codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, virtualhost, codeigniter-url

I am having a main portal, now this portal is going to be used by different institutes.

i have configured my apache virtual host as follows :

`<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/portal/exp1.php"
    ServerName test.exp1.org
  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/portal/exp1.php">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

`<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/portal/exp2.php"
    ServerName test.exp2.org.in
  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/portal/exp2.php">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

Now as you can see i have created different index pages like **exp1.php** , **exp2.php**

In each index page i have wrote somethig like this only

`header("Location: http://test.exp1.org/exp1.php/login/index/1")`
so now this will call login controller -> index function -> and parameter as 1.. so based on this parameter i will load a login page accordingly for that particular 1st institutes.

Same for other exp2.php

`header("Location: http://test.exp2.org/exp2.php/login/index/1")`
so now this will call login controller -> index function -> and parameter as 2.. so based on this parameter i will load a login page accordingly for that particular 2nd institutes.

After doing all this when i hit this on browser **http://test.exp1.org/** it shows me this error **The page isn't redirecting properly** , actually i want it to load particular view based on parameter passed in url.

this is my folder structure

[image]

know me were is my mistake or what all steps i should perform to make redirect properly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter (i use Laravel), but to me, this seems like apache not configured correctly.

This is the configuration i use on httpd-vhost.conf (example):

```
<VirtualHost nudistbeach.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@nudistbeach.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/nudistbeach/public/"
    ServerName nudistbeach.com
    ErrorLog "logs/test-laravel-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/test-laravel-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost revocs.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@revocs.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/revocs/public/"
    ServerName revocs.com
    ErrorLog "logs/test-laravel-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/test-laravel-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Try doing it like this and tell me the result:

```
<VirtualHost test.exp1.org:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.exp1.org
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/portal/exp1.php"
    ServerName test.exp1.org
    ErrorLog "logs/test-laravel-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/test-laravel-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost test.exp2.org:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.exp2.org
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/portal/exp2.php"
    ServerName test.exp2.org
    ErrorLog "logs/test-laravel-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/test-laravel-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```